# Android notification height and width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

I'm making an app that displays a custom notification in the notification bar, and would like to show the user a preview of their notification from inside the activity that creates the notification.

Is there a way through the Android API to get the height in pixels, or `dip` of a notification, so that I can match what the notification would look like as accurately as possible? Or does anyone know the height of notifications in Android 3.0 and later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the default notification bar height is 38 in hdpi, 25 in mdpi and 19 in ldpi

Answer (score 0):

You can create an xml layout for that notification, and that way control how big it is. Details can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html).

Answer (score -1):

[These guidelines](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html) from the official documentation* will answer questions regarding which sizes a developer *should* use. Methods to get the actual size of a `Drawable` can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html).

**Note that the link is from an old/archived developer documentation - but now... 10 years later... it's saved off at MIT!*

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @IlyaGazman fixed. Android sometimes removes their old documentation, but a simple Google search of the old URL found an archive of the original link.